# Spring Data IN clause adds additional brackets

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a 'Role' table with a 'name' column. I need to get all roles where names are either 'role1' or 'role2'. Role repository method looks like this:

```
Set<Role> findByNameIsIn(Set<String> roleNames);
```

My database contains only 'role1'. The request that is generated looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM ROLE WHERE (NAME IN ((?,?)))
    bind => [role1, role2]
```

Please notice the double brackets around the parameters. Result set is empty. When I try this query manually through the h2 console - no results as well. The following query works:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM ROLE WHERE (NAME IN ('role1', 'role2'))
```

My set contains two elements exactly. Sets should be supported as a parameter type. See:https://dzone.com/refcardz/core-spring-data

And finally the question: What am I missing?

Comment: Which persistence provider and database are you using? There a couple of bugs reported for various ones in that area.

Comment: EclipseLink + H2 embedded database

Comment: Broken since 2011… https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349477

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Oliver Gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-gierke) mentioned - there is a bug opened for this issue in EclipseLink (this is what I'm using as a persistence provider) issue tracker. Since 2011!.. Here is the workaround:

```
@Query("select r from Role r  where r.name in ?1")
Set<Role> findByNameIsIn(Set<String> roleNames);
```

And here is the valid generated query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM ROLE WHERE (NAME IN (?,?))
    bind => [role1, role2]
```